# What is the time complexity of string slice? O(k) or O(n)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity, slice

Is the time complexity of python str slice O(k) or O(n)?

The answers I am reading suggest its O(k) but I don't understand how.

For example

```
my_str = "thisismystringfortesting"

sub_str = my_str[3:10]
```

I understand its extracting only (k) characters, **but doesn't the operation have to convert the whole string into a list first before the slice?** My thought process is that the conversion of the entire string into a list alone would cost O(n). Unless only part of the string gets converted into a list?

So can someone please explain is string slicing on Python O(k) or O(n)?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why would it have to convert the entire string into a list?

Comment: What a bout profiling the behavior for exaples where `n` and `k` are very different?

Comment: Why would it need an intermediate list at all? This is presumably implemented in C, not in Python, so it can directly access the internal representation of the string and just copy the requested substring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76db37b1d37a9daadd9e5b320f2d5a53cd1352ec/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1579) and it is O(k) as it can be seen [line 1628](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76db37b1d37a9daadd9e5b320f2d5a53cd1352ec/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1628)

```
result_buf = PyBytes_AS_STRING(result);
for (cur = start, i = 0; i < slicelength;cur += step, i++) {
        result_buf[i] = source_buf[cur];
}
return result;
```